# Can a Gaussian Process predict random events?

Tags: modeling, nonparametric, gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I know that we can use Gaussian processes effectively for function approximation and regression. However,suppose there is a sequence of points in time $S = \{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n\}$, where $s_i$ can be either 0 or 1 at random. If we have a new point at a time i = n+1 and we want to predict if its state is 0 or 1 based on the given set $S$, can we use a Gaussian Process for this purpose?  and if so, how? is there a resource where such idea is explained?

Comment: +1.  There are even `R` packages for this: see http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/geoRglm/index.html, for instance.

Comment: I would go with a latent Gaussian process where the observables are the elements of the binary sequence. Something like Bernoulli observables with probability equal to the inverse logit of a linear combination of the outputs of the Gaussian process. At least as a starting point anyway.